# meteor android app won't connect to server

Tags: javascript, android, mongodb, meteor, modulus

I have a multiplayer bingo game which I made and im hosting it over Modulus. After uploading the project to Modulus and installing their MongoDB for my project, the multiplayer game works good over the browser, BUT, when I tried to meteor build the game and get the android .apk file to install over my Meizu device the installation got aborted and threw me a parse error so I decided to import the whole project to android studio and build the apk file from there. After installing the apk from Android Studio the application opens up, but it seems that it has no connection to the Modulus hosting server / Modulus db. Can anyone help and point me out my mistakes which I did? the build command was:

```
meteor build ../pathToBuild --server serverAdress
```

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well I solved this by hard coding the server's path inside the code

```
var theURL = "http://myServer";

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {

    // home
    theURL = "http://myServer";

    // office
    //theURL = "http://192.168.10.30:3000";

}

Meteor.absoluteUrl.defaultOptions.rootUrl = theURL;
process.env.ROOT_URL = theURL;
process.env.MOBILE_ROOT_URL = theURL;
process.env.MOBILE_DDP_URL = theURL;
process.env.DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL = theURL;
```

did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

This is generally to do with the way the server is started rather than the app, try specifying --mobile-server with the same address you use to build it when running the server you want to connect the app to:

`meteor --mobile-server http:/app.server:port`

If this works or if you don't run the app with the meteor command directly then you can set the DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL environmental variable on the server directory you are running from to avoid having to specify it each time you run the app.

Alternatively I think if you upgrade to meteor 1.3 and rebuild/deploy then this bug should disappear.

More info on [this thread](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3698#thread-subscription-status) although it's pretty long there are a few other things that can affect this in there but this method works for me for my cordova android app.